# Replacing an element from a tree with another Common LISP

Tags: tree, common-lisp, substitution

I'm trying to replace an element from a tree with another. So far I managed to replace the atom but it won't properly be added to the list

Code:

```
(defun replacing (tree trl wrl)
  (cond
    ((null tree) nil)
    ((atom tree)
     (cond ((eql tree trl) (list wrl))
           (t (list tree))))
    (t (apply 'nconc (mapcar #'(lambda (x) (replacing x trl wrl))
                             tree)))))
```

Example: `(replacing '(A (B) (C (D) (E))) 'D 'W) -> (A (B) (C (W) (E)))`

What I get: `(A B C W E)`

Any ideas what to change?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the case of an atom, just return the atom or its replacement. You return a list.

In the case of a tree, use mapcar to map the function over the subtrees. Get rid of the `NCONC`.

Common Lisp already has this functionality under the name [subst](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_substc.htm#subst):

```
CL-USER 1 > (subst 'W 'D '(A (D) (C (D) (D))))
(A (W) (C (W) (W)))
```

The code:

```
(defun replacing (tree trl wrl)
  (cond
   ((null tree) nil)
   ((atom tree)
    (if (eql tree trl) wrl tree))
   (t (mapcar #'(lambda (x)
                  (replacing x trl wrl))
              tree))))
```

Comment: I want to make it myself. I think I already did what you said. Look over my code and my final question.

Comment: @Melye77: look at my advice and your code. I told you already what to change.

Comment: But then nconc will throw an error. Nconc only works on lists

Comment: @Melye77: get rid of nconc.

Comment: Ooooh ok you were right. Got rid of (list ...) and used mapcar only. Thank you, worked!